# Line integral in proof of Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

In [wikipedia page about Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Proof_when_D_is_a_simple_region) the following equality appears:

$$
\int_{C_1} L(x,y)\, dx = \int_a^b L(x,g_1(x))\, dx
$$

I do not understand it. [Wikipedia page about line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) defines line integral, when applied to an scalar function, as:

$$
\int_{\mathcal{C}} f(\mathbf{r})\, ds = \int_a^b f\left(\mathbf{r}(t)\right)|\mathbf{r}'(t)| \, dt.
$$

that, applied to the proof expression and taken into account that the curve $C_1$ has been parametrized as $(x,g_1(x))$, gives (?):

$$
\int_{C_1} L(x,y)\, dx = \int_a^b L(x,g_1(x)) \,\, |(1,g_1'(x)| \,\, dx
$$

that seems different to the one said in the proof (all curve derivative term has been supresed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one integral is a $ds$ integral and the other integral is a $dx$ integral. Here, Green's Theorem is written in the $\int L\,dx+M\,dy$ form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the dx integral of an scalar function over a curve $C_1$ ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Look at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtII.aspx  Contrast it with the previous part on line integrals with respect to arc length.

Comment: @saulspatz: thanks a lot